# Cant see my membership provider in aspnet tools

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership

i am just creating a aspnet MVC 4 basic application with custom membership provider.
I follow these steps:

1) Create the membership tables in the Sql Server 2008 using aspnetregsql.exe
So i have the custom membership tables like:

aspnet_Users

aspnet_Membership

aspnet_Roles
...

2) Added a connection string refering to this database.

3) Added a provider in my web.config file inside the membership section:

```
<providers>
<clear />
<add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
         connectionStringName="primecontrol" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
         enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
         requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
         minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
         passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
```

So, when I run the ASP.NET configuration Tools and go to test my provider connection, it says that i dont create any providers.

But if i create a new user for example, it creates another tables in my database without the 'aspnet' prefix.
Whats going on?

Comment: Use this tutorial, he made thing a little bit different. Check it out http://logcorner.wordpress.com/2013/08/29/how-to-configure-custom-membership-and-role-provider-using-asp-net-mvc4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i am just creating a aspnet MVC 4 basic application with custom
>   membership provider.

***In the web.config, I do not see declaring custom membership provider.***

It should be like -

```
<membership defaultProvider="CustomProvider">
   <providers>
     <clear/>
        <add name="CustomProvider" 
         type="YourNamespace.YourMembershipProvider, YourNamespace" 
         ... />
   </providers>
</membership>
```

If you using ASP.Net MVC 4, you want to use new **[ASP.NET Universal Providers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx)** which is basically a newer version of **Legacy Membership Provider** that you are using.

**ASP.NET Universal Providers** uses **Entity Framework Code First** which is a lot cleaner compare to store procedures.

If you want to latest Membership, you might want to try [ASP.NET Identity](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/27/introducing-asp-net-identity-membership-system-for-asp-net-applications.aspx). Note: Identity is not backward compatible with **Legacy Membership Provider**.

Comment: why 'YourNamespace.YourMembershipProvider'? It not should be, 'type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider' ??

Comment: If you use [CustomMembershipProvider](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165159/Custom-Membership-Providers), you are supposed to use your class name with namespace. I think you meant ***DefaultMembershipProvider***, although you said you're creating ***CustomMembershipProvider***.

Comment: And for example, when i was using the old memberhip provider I was able to create the database with the aspnet_regsql command. But now with the universal provider I didnt get when the database tables are created. When it is created? And is it created without the 'aspnet_' prefix?

Comment: New ASP.NET Universal Providers creates tables without `aspnet_` prefix. In addition, EF code first only creates tables when the application is started. *(If no tables in the database, it'll create the required tables by itself automatically.)*

Comment: Sorry to bother you but theres something i cant understand. I create a separate dll with my models and my repositories with a BaseContext class and respective mappings and its working, now i can do crud operations with users. In my web config im using <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">. When i go to ASPNET Tools portal in the provider area, the only provider which i can see is the 'AspNetSqlProvider'. But in security area i can see the users that i created. Why i cannot see my 'DefaultMembershipProvider' overthere? Last question.